# Python Flask проблема с CORS

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, flask, cors

При отработке запроса возникает ошибка

> Запрос из постороннего источника заблокирован: Политика одного
> источника запрещает чтение удаленного ресурса на
> https://my.server.name:5000/postmethod. (Причина: не удалось выполнить
> запрос CORS). Код состояния: (null).

Код сервера

```py
import socket
from flask import Flask,render_template,request,jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
host = socket.gethostname()
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/postmethod', methods=['POST'])

def get_post_javascript_data():
    data = request.get_json()
    data = jsonify(data)
    data.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*')
    return data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host=host,ssl_context='adhoc')
```

Код javascript

```js
 $.post( "https://my.server.name:5000/postmethod", {
        encryption: JSON.stringify(value_post)});
```

Если я в браузере перехожу по ссылке https://my.server.name:5000/postmethod, появляется ошибка с угрозой безопасности. Код ошибки: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER.
Нажимаю "Принять риск и продолжить".
И только после этого запросы отправляются нормально.
Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё, разобрался.
Нужно сделать файлы ключа и сертификата

```py
import json
import socket
from flask import Flask,request,jsonify

host = socket.gethostname()
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/postmethod', methods=['POST'])
def get_post_javascript_data():
    data = request.form
    data = jsonify(data)
    data.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*')
    with open('user_settings.json','w') as f:
        json.dump(request.form,f,indent=4,ensure_ascii=False)
    return data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host=host,ssl_context=('root_ca.crt','root_ca.key'))
```

Comment: `with open('user_settings.json','w') as f:` а это зачем? :)

Comment: Да это уже потом мне надо сохранять данные в файле. Просто скопировал сюда весь код без правок